# Trouble linking boost libraries in Visial Studio 2010.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I compiled my boost libraries according to the guide found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010) and tried to use the boost filesystem library.

When I add `#include <boost\filesystem\operations.hpp>` I get the following errors:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00009A) "class boost::system::error_code __clrcall boost::filesystem2::detail::dir_itr_close(void * &)" (?dir_itr_close@detail@filesystem2@boost@@$$FYM?AVerror_code@system@3@AAPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __clrcall boost::filesystem2::detail::dir_itr_imp<class boost::filesystem2::basic_path<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct boost::filesystem2::path_traits> >::~dir_itr_imp<class boost::filesystem2::basic_path<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct boost::filesystem2::path_traits> >(void)" (??1?$dir_itr_imp@V?$basic_path@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@Upath_traits@filesystem2@boost@@@filesystem2@boost@@@detail@filesystem2@boost@@$$FQAM@XZ)
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0000A2) "class boost::system::error_category const & __clrcall boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@$$FYMABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __clrcall `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'void __clrcall boost::system::posix_category::A0x6367c629(void)''(void)" (???__E?A0x6367c629@posix_category@system@boost@@YMXXZ@?A0x6367c629@@$$FYMXXZ)
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0000A3) "class boost::system::error_category const & __clrcall boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@$$FYMABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __clrcall `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'void __clrcall boost::system::native_ecat::A0x6367c629(void)''(void)" (???__E?A0x6367c629@native_ecat@system@boost@@YMXXZ@?A0x6367c629@@$$FYMXXZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_code __clrcall boost::filesystem2::detail::dir_itr_close(void * &)" (?dir_itr_close@detail@filesystem2@boost@@$$FYM?AVerror_code@system@3@AAPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __clrcall boost::filesystem2::detail::dir_itr_imp<class boost::filesystem2::basic_path<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct boost::filesystem2::path_traits> >::~dir_itr_imp<class boost::filesystem2::basic_path<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct boost::filesystem2::path_traits> >(void)" (??1?$dir_itr_imp@V?$basic_path@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@Upath_traits@filesystem2@boost@@@filesystem2@boost@@@detail@filesystem2@boost@@$$FQAM@XZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __clrcall boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@$$FYMABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __clrcall `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'void __clrcall boost::system::posix_category::A0x6367c629(void)''(void)" (???__E?A0x6367c629@posix_category@system@boost@@YMXXZ@?A0x6367c629@@$$FYMXXZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __clrcall boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@$$FYMABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __clrcall `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'void __clrcall boost::system::native_ecat::A0x6367c629(void)''(void)" (???__E?A0x6367c629@native_ecat@system@boost@@YMXXZ@?A0x6367c629@@$$FYMXXZ)
```

If I compile without including operations.hpp it works fine. The thing is that when I use `#define BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC` It shows that it is linking in the boost libraries correctly:

```
Linking to lib file: libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib
Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib
```

Comment: Great suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 1):

In the project options (at linker option group) add the missing libraries at dependencies, and add the path to boost libraries in the additional directories. Or, to enable automatic linking (if you compiled boost as DLLs) define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK in the preprocessor symbols in C++ options, in the project.