# Problems compiling boost program

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile a simple c++ file in Visual Studio express 2012 on windows 64 bit. I installed boost_1_53_0 using the visual studio command prompt. I also compiles/installed the boost libs.

Here is my include's:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
```

I'm getting the following errors when I try to debug or release my 'project'.

http://pastebin.com/fBDcttKc

I have correctly set the additional include directories, and the additional library directories settings.

If I'm missing some info please tell me, I have just started learning c++

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Very informative post, I will look through it. -Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [was already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977503/trouble-linking-boost-libaries-in-visial-studio-2010).
The idea is to either enable autolinking or link with proper libraries.

> define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK in the preprocessor symbols in C++ options,
>   in the project.