# python3 install mysqlclient and get error :‘MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH’ undeclared

Tags: python

```
[root@bigdata01 mysqlclient-python-master]# python3 setup.py install

/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:331: UserWarning: Normalizing '2.0.0dev1' to '2.0.0.dev1'
  normalized_version,
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing mysqlclient.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to mysqlclient.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to mysqlclient.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,0,'dev',1) -D__version__=2.0.0dev1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/local/python3/include/python3.5m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX
MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize’:
MySQLdb/_mysql.c:533: error: ‘MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
MySQLdb/_mysql.c:533: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
MySQLdb/_mysql.c:533: error: for each function it appears in.)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

my OS is Centos6.7 and the default python version is 2.6 . so I install python3

```
[root@bigdata01 mysqlclient-python-master]# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

How could I solve this problem? Any answer will be appreciated , thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 install mysqlclient==1.4.4
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77965955/9913319