# C++ Simple UDP Server

Tags: c++, udp

What is the simplest way to have a udp server in c++ and be able to receive its messages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp

Comment: I downloaded the boost zip file, what part of it do I need? I only need the asio part...

Comment: almost all boost libraries use some common code for versioning, configuration etc. so you cannot simply extract Asio. to use Asio you need to compile boost.thread and boost.system, the rest is header-only stuff, pls correct me

Comment: found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: @Neb: you can also use asio without boost, see http://think-async.com/

Comment: @Hasturkun that's not entirely accurate, you still need boost installed to use asio. Specifically, linking against `boost-system` is required.

Comment: @Sam Miller: It really doesnt, see http://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio , the non-boost Asio does not have any dependency on Boost, and is a header only implementation