# Boost and Python 3.x

Tags: c++, python, boost, python-3.x, boost-python

How does boost.python deal with Python 3? Is it Python 2 only?

Comment: Seems that they are working on it. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/python/doc/news.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Newer versions of Boost should work fine with Python V3.x. This support has been added quite some time ago, I believe after a successful Google Summer of Code project back in 2009.

The way to use Python V3 with Boost is to properly configure the build system by adding for instance:

```
using python : 3.1 : /your_python31_root ;
```

to your user-config.jam file.

Comment: You can simply do `./bootstrap.sh --with-python-version=X.Y` if it is installed on the system and detectable (in the usual place). If not, you can specify these options (instead of editing a file) on the command line. See `./bootstrap.sh --help`

Comment: Turns out, the space between the python path and the semicolon... is important!

Answer (score 10):

libboostpython needs to be built with python3 in order to do this. **This doesn't work with boost 1.58** (which comes with Ubuntu 16.04), so make sure you download the latest boost distribution. I just did this with boost_1_64_0.

As mentioned above, find the file "user-config.jam" in you boost code distribution, and copy it to $HOME.

```
cp /path/to/boost_1_64_0/tools/build/example/user-config.jam $HOME
```

Then edit the python line (the last line) so that is says:

```
using python : 3.5 : /usr/bin/python3 : /usr/include/python3.5m : /usr/lib ;
```

This is correct for Ubuntu 16.04. You can use pkg-config to find the correct include directory.

```
user@computer > pkg-config --cflags python3
-I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.5m
```

And you only need the first include directory.

Then build boost from scratch. (Sorry.) I install it to /usr/local

```
cd /path/to/boost_1_64_0
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
./b2 
sudo ./b2 install
```

Now jump into the python example directory, and build the tutorial

```
cd /path/to/boost_1_64_0/libs/python/example/tutorial
bjam
```

This will not build correctly if you have a system install of boost, because, under the hood, bjam is linking to libboostpython using the g++ parameter "-lboost". But, on Ubuntu 16.04, this will just go and find "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0", and then the python bindings will fail to load. In fact, you'll get his error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
```

If you want to see the g++ commands that bjam is using, do this:

```
user@computer > bjam -d2 -a | grep g++
g++  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c -o "hello.o" "hello.cpp"
g++ -o hello_ext.so -Wl,-h -Wl,hello_ext.so -shared -Wl,--start-group hello.o  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lboost_python -ldl -lpthread -lutil -Wl,--end-group
```

Here we see the problem, you need "-L/usr/includ/lib" just before "-lboost_python". So execute this to link the shared library correctly:

```
g++ -o hello_ext.so -Wl,-h -Wl,hello_ext.so -shared -Wl,--start-group hello.o  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_python -ldl -lpthread -lutil -Wl,--end-group
```

You may need to rerun ldconfig (or reboot)

```
sudo ldconfig
```

And you are finally ready to go:

```
user@computer > python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hello_ext
>>> hello_ext.greet()
'hello, world'
>>> exit()
```

Comment: this was totally helpful to me.  the key to getting my project to build with a custom-installed everything (gcc, python3, boost) was to edit my `project-config.jam` file, as you indicated.  namely, to adjust the `using python :...` line to list each of binary executable for the python3 interpreter, the include folder for it, and the lib directory.  after re-building boost and installing, my project correctly builds using python 3.  thanks!

Comment: Nicely explained. very helpful!

Answer (score 7):

Yes this question is super old, but I had to do something that wasn't specified in any of the answers here (though it was built off some of the suggestions), so I'll quickly jot down my entire process:

1. Download boost_X_Y_Z.tar.bz2 (I used boost 1.68.0)
2. `tar --bzip2 -xf boost_1_68_0.tar.bz2` (where you want folder to be temporarily)
3. `cd boost_1_68_0`
4. `./bootstrap.sh --with-python-version=3.6 --prefix=/usr/local`
5. `./b2`
6. `sudo ./bjam install`
7. `cp tools/build/example/user-config.jam $HOME`, then modify the contents of this file to say `using python : 3.6 : /usr/bin/python3 : /usr/include/python3.6m : /usr/lib ;` (or whatever folders are appropriate for your environment)

Given this C++ source file `BoostPythonHelloWorld.cpp`:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* say_hi()
{
    return "Hi!";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(BoostPythonHelloWorld)
{
    boost::python::def("say_hi", say_hi);
}
```

And this Python script `BoostPythonHelloWorld.py`:

```
import BoostPythonHelloWorld
print(BoostPythonHelloWorld.say_hi())
```

It can be compiled and ran as such:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -I/path/to/boost_1_68_0 -I/usr/include/python3.6 /other_path/to/BoostPythonHelloWorld.cpp
gcc -shared -Wall -Werror -Wl,--export-dynamic BoostPythonHelloWorld.o -L/path/to/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib -lboost_python36 -o BoostPythonHelloWorld.so
python3 BoostPythonHelloWorld.py
```

The part that was different for me was `-Wl,--export-dynamic BoostPythonHelloWorld.o`, I had not seen that anywhere else, and I was getting a Python error concerning an undefined symbol until I added that.

Hope this helps someone down the line!

Comment: This particular answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086375/4040307
I had the latest version boost_1_71_0

Comment: To get the options available ./bootstrap.sh --help. There are 3 options related to python: --with-python=PYTHON --with-python-root=DIR --with-python-version=X.Y. If command option works, then it is more preferable to modifying user-config.jam. The later has potential problem if your python3 changes from one source to another.

Answer (score 4):

If you get "error: No best alternative for /python_for_extension" be sure to have

```
using python : 3.4 : C:\\Python34 : C:\\Python34\\include : C:\\Python34\\libs ;
```

[only in user-config.jam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592485/error-compiling-boost-python-quickstart) in your home path and nowhere else. 
Use double backslashes when compiling under windows with mingw (toolset=gcc) or MSVC (toolset=msvc).
Compile with cmd, not msys, and if you also have python 2.7 installed remove that from PATH in that shell.
First do

```
bootstrap.bat gcc/msvc
```

assuming you have the gcc/msvc tools available via PATH (/ for the alternatives, but use only one, or leave away)

Afterward you can also do

```
booststrap.sh --with-bjam=b2
```

in msys to generate a project-config.jam, but need to edit it to remove the "using python" and "/usr",..

Then the following

```
b2 variant=debug/shared link=static/shared toolset=gcc/msvc > b2.log
```

With static the python quickstart examples did not work for me, although I would prefer to do without the boost_python dll.

I did not try on linux, but it should be more straightforward there.

Answer (score 3):

You can even specify the python distribution via

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=<path to your python binary>
```

e.g.

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python3
```

for your system's python3 or

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python
```

for the python version of your currently active virtual env python.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655683/2924323) to know how to build `boost` with `python`. It shows the way to build with `python2` with Visual Studio 10.0 (2010). But I go through the same procedure for a project that I am currently working on and it works fine with python 3.5 and Visual Studio 14.1 (2017).

If you get [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729259/wrapping-c-class-with-boost-python-in-visual-studio-2017) when building your python boost project, just add `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` value to `Preprocessor Definitions` (inside C\C++ > preprocessor tab) in your project properties.
And also, do not forget to add `boost .dll` files location to your system path.

Answer (score 1):

When the path to Python contains spaces, you will be in for quite a ride.  After a whole lot of trial and error, I finally managed to get something that works.  Behold my `user-config.jam` (which has to be in my home directory for `bjam` to find it):

```
import toolset : using ;

using python : 3.6
         : \"C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\python.exe\"
         : C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\include
         : C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\libs
         ;
```

The inconsistent quoting is intended and seems to be required.  With this I can build boost-python and use it as `Boost::python36` in my `CMakeLists.txt`.  Still, one issue remains: I have to link to python manually viz

```
target_link_libraries(MyTarget
    Boost::boost Boost::python36
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/libs/python36.lib")
target_include_directories(MyTarget PRIVATE
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/include")
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding "Using Python : 3 etc." into **user-config.jam** in my home directory didn't work. I had to add the line into **project-config.jam** instead, which resides in the root directory of unpacked boost.

Specifically the line was:

using python : 3.9 : /usr/bin/python3 : /usr/include/python3.9 : /usr/lib ;

and the version of boost was 1_78_0