# How to Build Using the Boost Python Libraries in VS2017

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2017, boost-python

I have built the Boost 1.64.0 Python libraries, using MS Visual Studio Professional 2017 and 32-bit Python 3.4.  Now, when I write an application against the resulting library, I'm getting the following link error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_python-vc141-mt-1_64.lib'

I have looked in the *stage/lib* directory, and indeed, the library is named *libboost_python**3**-vc141-mt-1_64.lib* (note the **3** in the name).  I'm assuming the 3 is referencing the fact that the Boost Python library was generated using Python 3.  Why is there a naming inconsistency between the library that was built, and the library that my project is attempting to import?  Is it simply a missing macro definition in my project configuration?

Comment: Some people who have python2 and python3 on their system will name python3 pyhon3 instead of python. I imagine that this could be the root of your problem but I really don't know.

Comment: In `VCC++ Directories -> Include Directories`, add your `c:\....\Python36_3\include` path. I'm almost sure it will make things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSVC builds, the `boost` headers use [MSVC #pragma comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) to `autolink` to the `boost` libraries, see `boost/config/auto_link.hpp`.

In addition to including `auto_link.hpp`, the `boost/python/detail/config.hpp` file contains:

```
// Set the name of our library, this will get undef'ed by auto_link.hpp
// once it's done with it:
//
#define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python
```

Which is why MSVC is trying to `autolink` to `libboost_python-vc141-mt-1_64.lib`.

Clearly your `boost` build has built `libboost_python3-vc141-mt-1_64.lib` instead. As suggested by @kpie, your `boost` build may have named the python library file depending upon whether it's built for python 3 or python 2...

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539557/boost-and-python-3-x) question describes how to build `boost` for `python 3`. It may answer your macro question regarding the build.

To fix the issue, you could [disable autolinking](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-developers-archive/Fidh1sok1bw), or simply rename the library file to remove the "3".

Comment: After having read through the questions and answers you linked, I'm still a little confused as to the correct path forward. I understand your suggestion to disable autolinking; does that imply that there is no way to use auto-linking with Boost Python 3?  When you suggest to rename the file, is that a configuration option that is set in user-config.jam, or are you suggesting I manually rename the file in Windows Explorer? I find it difficult to believe that the Boost Python designers would force the generated library name to be different than the name being auto-linked, with no way to fix it.

Comment: Based on some of the questions you linked, I have tried to define the `PY_MAJOR_VERSION=3` macro, which didn't have any effect.  I have also tried to add the Python 3 include directory as the first entry in my Additional Include Directories setting, which also didn't work.  I may try to remove the explicit version from my user-config.jam file, and see if that generates the library without the "3" in the name.

Comment: My boost builds contain *both* `python` and `python3` libraries, I think that your user-config.jam file may be causing the problem. `MSVC boost` pre-built binaries are available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.64.0/) they also contain both. I recommend that you use simply one of them.

Comment: Interesting... my user-config.jam file is in *tools\build\src*, and contains only two lines: `import toolset : using ;`, and `using python : 3.4 : C:\\Python34 ;`.  To build Boost, I am running `bootstrap`, followed by `.\b2 address-model=32 stage`.  Is any of this appreciably different than how you are building Boost?  Perhaps *stage* isn't the correct target.

Comment: @Jeff G I'm pretty sure that `stage` is the correct target! I build `boost` using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257), although for `MSVC 17` it should now use `toolset=msvc-14.1`

Comment: Thanks for the link... I followed those instructions, and still didn't get a boost python library without the *3* in the name.  Ultimately, I just created two symbolic links (using the `mklink` command) without the *3* in their name, to point to the boost build output.

Comment: @Jeff G I think that the symbolic links are a far better solution than my renaming suggestion. I'm glad to hear that it works.