# Boost signals.hpp causes several compile time errors on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I'm trying to use boost.signals library. I know that to use it, first I need to build the boost since signals is not a header only library. I followed the steps described under [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010/2641513#2641513) to build the boost and did not get any errors. However, when I include boost/signals.hpp I get several C2146, C2238, C2447 errors. Most of them are syntax errors. For example there are several C2143 errors saying that `missing ; before {` in **signals_common.hpp**.

Has anyone faced such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get a linker error if it were a problem with how you built it.  This is compile time.

Try making a simple example for people to try.

My guess would be Qt.  If you are using Qt, there may be namespace conflicts.

[How do I get Boost.Signals to work with Qt?](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals/s04.html#id2861476)