# Failed to build boost

Tags: c++, c, boost

I have been able to compile boost on Windows Vista using the following commands:

```
bootstrap.bat

bjam.exe --with-filesystem --with-thread --toolset=msvc
```

However, when I issue the same command on Windows 7, I get this:

```
'failed to write output file 'bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-8.0\release\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_thread-vc80-mt-1_48.lib.rsp'!'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate. Either way, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010) should give you everything you need...

Comment: Does boost log detail error in a log file while compiling boost?

Comment: Depends on you specified compilation options. It can me made to dump an error log I belive. But I am no expert, I have built is a handfull of times and never had any major issues. Check the manual [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/index.html) or do some more digging in the link I gave above. All the best...

Comment: how is C tag related?

Answer (score 8):

I had this and the problem turned out to be that boost seems to have some problems with long path names. Moved the directories up a couple of levels and it all started working. But had me pulling my hair out for a while

Comment: God bless you sir. Had to run cmake and msbuild commands for amazon gamelift and couldn't understand for the longest time what the issue. Whoever you are, you are my hero!

Answer (score 6):

You can use bjam.exe --abbreviate-paths

Found here: http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2007/01/16028.php

I had similar problem and this switch helped me a lot (although it is not documented).

Comment: The options '--abbreviate-paths' and '--hash' are now documented: [3.4.2. Options](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.options). The option '--hash' produces shorter paths.