# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

Seem I can't get this to work. I made a simple console application (which depend on `websocket++` library) which need `Boost` libraries.. but when I try to compile I get:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib'

However, I did the bjam which created the lib in `(boost_root)/stage/libs` and I linked the path to the libs to the compiler `C++/Additionnals includes`.

If I look in `(boost_root)/stage/libs` the file  `libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib` is not there. It is called `libboost_system-vc110-mt-sgd-1_51.lib` instead.

Any idea?

Comment: Ive been able to build the libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib file doing a complete build with bjam however i still get the error.

Comment: Open the `VS2012 developer command prompt`, go to your boost root directory and type `bootstrap`, and then type `b2` and you should get a complete set of library files.

Comment: Did you add the include paths and linker paths to your project?

Comment: Are you building your application with `/MD` ?

Comment: If it's okay to download instead of compile, get the libs from here:
http://code.ingres.com/boostlib/trunk/stage/lib/

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The *C++ → General → Additional Include Directories* parameter is for listing directories where the compiler will search for header files.

You need to tell the linker where to look for libraries to link to. To access this setting, right-click on the project name in the *Solution Explorer* window, then *Properties → Linker → General → Additional Library Directories*. Enter `<boost_path>\stage\lib` here (this is the path where the libraries are located if you [build Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655683/241631) using default options).

Comment: can u explain me what is the boost_path

Comment: @ggsmartboy It's the path where the boost source files are (the same path that you list in the compiler include paths so it can find the boost headers). The answer assumes that you built boost yourself (not using a distribution) using the default build options.

Comment: Awesome.  Saved me a real headache too.  Why I seemed unable to spot this in the boost documentation (if it is even there), I don't know! :)

Comment: The settings referred to in this answer are found if you right click on the _project_ and choose properties (for noobs like me, right clicking the solution, going to Tools > Options etc. Those options were not present on all my projects though). VS2013

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D You're right, I did assume the reader knew that part. Updated.

Comment: Well, i don't have folder "stage" in boost 1.64

Comment: @Archont As the last sentence says, you need to build Boost for that directory to exist.

Comment: Why it is not working for me I built boost then done as mentioned in the answer still that error is not gone!!:(\

Answer (score 119):

This is the simplest way for an amateur like me who is studying C++ on their own:

First Unzip the boost library to any directory of your choice. I recommend `c:\directory`.

1. Open your visual C++.
2. Create a new project.
3. Right click on the project.
4. Click on property.
5. Click on C/C++.
6. Click on general.
7. Select additional include library.
8. Include the library destination. e.g. `c:\boost_1_57_0`.
9. Click on pre-compiler header.
10. Click on create/use pre-compiled header.
11. Select not using pre-compiled header.

Then go over to the link library were you experienced your problems.

1. Go to were the extracted file was `c:\boost_1_57_0`.
2. Click on `booststrap.bat` (don't bother to type on the command window just wait and don't close the window that is the place I had my problem that took me two weeks to solve. After a while the `booststrap` will run and produce the same file, but now with two different names: `b2`, and `bjam`.
3. Click on `b2` and wait it to run.
4. Click on `bjam` and wait it to run. Then a folder will be produce called `stage`.
5. Right click on the project.
6. Click on property.
7. Click on linker.
8. Click on general.
9. Click on include additional library directory.
10. Select the part of the library e.g. `c:\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib`.

And you are good to go!

Comment: Thanks very much Wu Jie - I had never done anything like this before and these steps were exactly what I needed to build Boost and produce the missing 'libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_57.lib' library file I was having trouble linking :)

Comment: Thanks, I like nice detailed instructions. For step 2/3/4 of setting up boost, what I instead did was: a) open a commandline prompt *as root*; b) change to the boost_1_57_0 directory; c) type `bootstrap.bat` (it took 10-20 seconds); d) type `./b2` as instructed (it then took 30-40 minutes to complete).

Comment: I had to open ***bootstrap.bat*** using the Visual Studio command prompt, as the regular command prompt did not know how to process the 'cl' command.

Comment: 2/20/2018, your solution works for me (VS2017 + Boost 1.66).  Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for the steps for beginners. I wish everyone would always give answers like you have given.

Comment: I would add an extra step: adding `#define  BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` before importing `Boost.Python`: it seems that Boost uses dynamic library by default. Forcing it to use shared libs solved the (exact same) problem for me

Answer (score 8):

Yet another solution:

I was stumped because I was including boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib in my Link->Additional Dependencies property, but the link kept telling me it couldn't open libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib (note the lib prefix).  I didn't specify libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib.

I was trying to use (and had built) the boost dynamic libraries (.dlls) but did not have the BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK macro defined.  Apparently there are hints in the compile to include a library, and without BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK it looks for the static library (with the lib prefix), not the dynamic library (without a lib prefix).

Comment: Still only 1 upvote, yet I find myself here every few months, being reminded again what the solution is to my problem!!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It was caused because I compiled the Boost with the Visual C++ 2010(v100) and I tried to use the library with the Visual Studio 2012 (v110) by mistake.

So, I changed the configurations (in Visual Studio 2012) going to *Project properties* -> *General* -> *Plataform Toolset* and change the value from *Visual Studio 2012 (v110)* to *Visual Studio 2010 (v100)*.

Comment: I hope you realize that when you change the platform toolset to use v100, you're telling the VS2012 IDE to use the compiler that shipped with VS2010. Any C++11 features that were added to the VS2012 compiler will not be available. A better solution is to compile Boost using the VS2012 compiler; you can have the generated libraries from both 2010 and 2012 co-exist because Boost puts the compiler version number into the output filenames.

Comment: You're right and I'm aware. I afraid of what might happen if I upgrade the libraries and the compiler. So, when the project is finished I will fix all this stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and my mistake was that I had installed the binary boost_1_55_0-msvc-11.0-32.exe to use with visual c++ 2010 which has the version v100  (project properties->ConfiguratioProperties->General->platformTooset) not v110 as visual c++ 2012. So I dowloaded boost_1_55_0-msvc-10.0-32.exe and now everything is ok so far.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when trying to use **boost unit testing** in **Visual Studio 2015** (Community Edition):

> fatal error LNK1104: libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_57

so I thought I'd share my solution.

You can create a boost unit testing project in of of two ways (and this solution works for both):

1. using the [Boost Unit Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5f4ae1bd-b769-410e-8238-fb30beda987f)
2. or by creating a Win32 Console Application ([steps here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide)), and substituting the main function with a boost unit testing function ([steps here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html)).

Here are the steps I followed to get both projects to work:

First, download the desired boost version (for example, [boost_1_57_0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_57_0.html)). You can either download boost with the correct binaries (compiled using msvc v140), or extract the binaries yourself by running the following commands from command line:

1. bootstrap.bat
2. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
3. bjam --clean
4. bjam -j4 --debug-symbols=on --build-type=complete toolset=msvc-14.0 threading=multi runtime-link=shared
   address-model=32

Where **msvc-14.0** specifies that we require the Visual Studio 2015 version (VS 2015 = v14.0 = v140), and **address-model=32** specifies that we require platform 32 (but the same can be done for 64 bit).

Once you have the binaries, go to Visual Studio, select the Boost Unit Testing project you have created. Go to **Project properties > configuration** (from the main menu) and make the following choices:

- Set the "**General > Platform Toolset**" to Visual Studio 2015 (v140).
- Include the path to the boost folder (e.g. C:\boost_1_57_0) and the path to the subfolder containing the binary files (e.g. C:\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib) in:

  - "**C\C++ > Additional Include Directory**"
  - and "**Linker > Additional Library Directories**".

Answer (score 3):

b2 -j%cores% toolset=%msvcver% address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=minimal stage --stagedir=stage/x64

Properties → Linker → General → Additional Library Directories
$(BOOST)\stage\**x64**\lib

Comment: A bit more elaboration on what are those lines doing and why -> would help to improve the quality of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have trouble building boost or prefer not to do that, an alternative is to download the lib files from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.51.0/).  The link will take you to a folder of zipped lib and dll files for version 1.51.  But, you should be able to edit the link to specify the version of choice.  Apparently the installer from BoostPro has some issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, have you tried using Tools / NuGet Package Manager to install boost_program_options-vcXXX? This is an easy way of installing boost.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue reported here. 
I solved the issue moving the mainTest.cpp from a subfolder src/mainTest/ to the main folder src/
I guess this was your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

`2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_55.lib`

In my case, bootstrap/bjam was not available (libraries were precompiled and committed to SCM) on old inherited project. Libraries did not have VC or BOOST versioning in their filenames eg: `libboost_regex-mt-sgd.lib`, however `Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_55.lib` was somehow triggered automatically.

Fixed by manually adding the non-versioned filename to:

```
<AdditionalDependencies>$(DK_BOOST)\lib64\libboost_regex-mt-sgd.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
```

and blacklisting the `...vc120-mt-sgd-1_55.lib` in

```
<IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_55.lib</IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error on my Visual Studio 2012 with boost 1.60: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_60.lib'

I fixed this issue  by downloading boost binaries:

- Download boost binary from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/. For example: https://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost-binaries/1.60.0/boost_1_60_0-msvc-11.0-32.exe?viasf=1
- Save the file at a directory. e.g. C:\boost_1_60_0
- Run the downloaded exe file
- In Visual Studio, modify Additional Include Directories for the project to  include the boost directory. e.g. C:\boost_1_60_0
- In Visual Studio, modify additional library directory for the project to include the lib directory. e.g. C:\boost_1_60_0\lib32-msvc-11.0