# Boost Link Error

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I have installed the boost library and I have Linked both lib and include directories to my solution. As well as setting to *Not Using Precompiled Headers*. But when I test the simple provided example, I get the Link error when it builds.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'libboost_regex-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib'

I have searched the lib folder and this lib file does not exist. I downloaded and installed again and it is not there. It looks like it has been emitted in this version of boost.

Btw, I have installed all the varients of regex and I am using the VS12.

UPDATE: If anyone else has the same problem try **NOT** to use boost installer and build it yourself.

Comment: not the same problem as this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042561/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-system-vc110-mt-gd-1-51-lib

Comment: Have you built boost libraries?

Comment: @IgorR.        No I have installed the libraries via the installer from BoostPro

Comment: @Erfan Well, then you have to see how regex debug lib is named in this installation - perhaps its naming have some other layout. But the most simple solution is build boost on your own and have appropriate names, it's quite trivial.

Comment: @75inchpianist it's kind of different. since I used the boost installer it did not contain the stage folder. Also I checked the lib files on sourceforge and it didn't have that either. But after building it myself I got all the lib files needed.

Comment: @IgorR. I built it and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the Boost libraries have to be built -

> The only Boost libraries that must be built separately are:
>   ...
>   Boost.Regex

(from [Header-Only Libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries))

The easy (but not recommended) way is to download required binary from Internet. For example - [boostlib - Revision 9: /trunk/stage/lib](http://code.ingres.com/boostlib/trunk/stage/lib/).
Then add it in  *Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories*