# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, xml-serialization

I use Boost serialization to create a simple XML file, but when debug, I got this error
"error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib'"
I have tried to fixed my problem followed the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042561/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-system-vc110-mt-gd-1-51-lib)

but I can't find the folder "stage" in my Boost folder, I downloaded Boost from [here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/)

Comment: You have to build the Boost libraries first. I suggest you read the [Getting started guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to build the boost libraries first.

Open a console and go to the root folder of boost. Then type

```
bootstrap
```

and then type

```
b2 variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static
```

for building debug and release configuration for static linking. You can find more information in the [Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

Comment: He isn't looking for the static version, -gd is the dynamic one.

Comment: Ok so `b2 variant=debug,release link=shared` should do.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I'm using boost 1.55, in which `serialization`  is a pure template module. There are only some hpp files in the module folder. However, I still get the same error.

My solution is to

```
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
```

in the code. Now everything goes fine.