# How to solve fatal error LNK1181 when compiling

Tags: visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build [ORBSLAM2](https://github.com/Alkaid-Benetnash/ORB_SLAM2) on Windows with Visual Studio 2015 v14 x64. This particular branch of ORBSLAM2 has a dependency to the [C/C++ Boost](https://www.boost.org/) library.

I have performed the following steps so far:

**A.) I downloaded and built the Boost library like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663302/error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-serialization-vc110-mt-gd-1-53-lib):**

```
$ bootstrap.bat
$ b2 link=static runtime-link=static release stage
$ bjam install --toolset=msvc variant=release link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static
```

**B.) Then I configured the following properties for the project:**

> Project Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

```
D:\ORB_SLAM2\Thirdparty\boost_1_64_0\
```

> Project Properties -> Linker -> Input-> Additional Dependencies

```
D:\ORB_SLAM2\Thirdparty\boost_1_64_0\stage\lib\
```

**I get the following linker error while building:**

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  Checking Build System
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/ORB_SLAM2/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ORB_SLAM2, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>  Building Custom Rule D:/ORB_SLAM2/CMakeLists.txt
2>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/ORB_SLAM2/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>  System.cc
2>  Tracking.cc
2>  LocalMapping.cc
2>  LoopClosing.cc
2>  ORBextractor.cc
...
...
...
2>  Viewer.cc
2>  Generating Code...
2>  ORB_SLAM2.vcxproj -> D:\ORB_SLAM2\build\Release\ORB_SLAM2.lib
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: mono_euroc, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>  mono_euroc.cc
3>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\ORB_SLAM2\Thirdparty\boost_1_64_0\stage\lib\.obj'
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The strange thing is, that the linker is only looking for `.obj`, there's no file name involved. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing the Boost libraries with `NuGet Packet Manager` within the Visual Studio 2015 IDE.

1. Right-click solution -> `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`
2. Browse "boost" and select `boost-vc140` (by Sergey Shandar)
3. On the right side, select desired version and check projects you want link `Boost` with
4. Hit "Install" -> OK -> wait, be patient ...
5. Right-click your project -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories:
       Add "`C:\<path-to-your-project>\build\packages\boost.1.64.0.0\lib\native\include`"
6. Right-click your project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies:
       Add "`C:\<path-to-your-project>\build\packages\boost_serialization-vc140.1.64.0.0\lib\native\address-model-64\lib\libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-1_64.lib`"