# Fatal Error with boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib'
```

I have faced this error while compiling, I searched for the file and I found it, so what is the problem?

Comment: Check if the file is in the linker search path.

Comment: [See If this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042561/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-system-vc110-mt-gd-1-51-lib)

Comment: @HamzaAnis This doesn't help, i updated boost. same problem!

Comment: @bluebrother yeah, it's in the linker search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen due to a variety of reasons.
Here are a few from my own experiences:

- check if there is an architecture missmatch. (eg. your app is x64, but the boost libraries are x32)
- check if you configured the active build configuration in VS (Debug vs Release)
- check if the boost libraries are available in the `Additional Library Directories` under the linker properties in VS.
- check if you use the correct platform toolset in VS. (v140 in your case).