# Visual C++: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I unzipped [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) library in

C:\boost

and ran

```
bootstrap.bat
b2.exe install
```

via Visual Studio 2017's Developer Command Prompt.

It created two folders for me:

```
C:\boost\include
C:\boost\lib
```

Which I added to

```
VC++ Directories > Include Directories
Linker > General > Additional Library Directories
```

Respectively.

Now, building the following code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0501
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following error:

```
1>main.cpp
1>Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'
```

It is surprising for me that `VC++` looks for `libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib` while the built `lib` files are:

```
libboost_system-vc-mt-1_55.lib
libboost_system-vc-mt-gd-1_55.lib
```

Which is missing a number. Is it related to the warnings poping up during building of `Boost`?

> Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results

---

**Update:**

Please do not link this question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042561/). The path is correct as I have run `b2.exe` with `install` switch. In addition, the option ( C++ → General → Additional Include Directories parameter) is related to old visual Studio IDE. I know it is very stupid to explain such basics. But unfortunately, I see a strong insist on such a linking.

**Update:**

It is a shame that a gang of users mark this question as a duplicate by linking to a wrong question while they know they are wrong. If you make a mistake, do not insist on it.

Comment: Perhaps it's a better idea to use [latest boost 1.64](http://www.boost.org/users/download/)

Comment: @KenWhite, The path I have picked is absolutely correct. The other path generates the same error.

Comment: @KenWhite, Have you worked with C++ at all?

Comment: It's a shame that you insist on ranting instead of giving a clear technical description why this duplicate doesn't apply here. If you want to be treated with respect here, try to show that respect to those people that make up this community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes most likely this is related. Boost build is unable to determine Visual Studio compiler version, so it is writing generalized lib names like `libboost_system-vc-mt-1_55.lib`. Header is trying to use last known version of Visual Studio, for the Boost 1.55 (which is VS2013 or vs120). Try using [last](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_64_0.html) version of the boost, it should support VS2017.