# Boost Library Build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I try to build boost library for visual studio. I follow [Boost Lib Build instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) and [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010). Open Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) as adminstator and run bootstrap.bat. Then, build failed. I look at .log file more information.

#### Using 'vc10' toolset.

Generating Code...

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

There is 1 interface on the system:

Name : Wi-Fi

...

Hosted network status : Not started

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'There.obj'

I'm not sure it is enough for you to understand error, but I don't have anything else. Also I changed tools/build/v2/engine/build.bat and remove this part;

```
if NOT "_%VS110COMNTOOLS%_" == "__" (

    set "BOOST_JAM_TOOLSET=vc11"

    set "BOOST_JAM_TOOLSET_ROOT=%VS110COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\"

    goto :eof)

call :Clear_Error

if EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\VCVARSALL.BAT" (

    set "BOOST_JAM_TOOLSET=vc11"

    set "BOOST_JAM_TOOLSET_ROOT=%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\"

    goto :eof)

call :Clear_Error
```

I use VS2010 and win8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same.

Clean your boost folder (bin.v2 and stage folders), then call

```
set VS120COMNTOOLS=
```

and call once again (sampel below is for x64, for x32 change your address-model accordingly):

```
bootstrap.bat
b2 address-model=64 toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete stage --with-filesystem --with-signals --with-system
```