# Building/including Boost.Python in VS2013

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-python

Can someone tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

I'm on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2013 and I would like to be able to be able to setup a simple Boost.Python project. I don't know if I've made something wrong **building** boost or when **including** boost in my project.

**Error**

When I try to `#include` any boost python module, e.g. `#include <boost/python/module.hpp>` I get the following error in Visual Studio.

```
1>c:\boost_1_55_0\boost\python\detail\wrap_python.hpp(50): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pyconfig.h': No such file or directory
```

**Building**

I tried to follow instructions from [this SO thread in which KTC addresses Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655683/1937742), and [this Python howto from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/building.html), but since both links are bit dated, are doing things differently, and some of the steps seems to have changed in newer versions of Boost, I had to improvise on some of the instructions.

This is what I did.

1. Unziped the latest version (1.55) of Boost source file to `C:\boost_1_55_0`.
2. Used `cmd.exe` to navigate to `C:\boost_1_55_0`. (I did not use `Developer Command Prompt for VS2013` found under `\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts`. This shouldn't make any difference, should it? [Boosts official guide for 1.55](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) didn't make any specific mentioning of using `Command Prompt for VS2013`.
3. Used `bootstrap` in cmd.
4. Edited `project-config.jam` (created by `bootstrap`) and added path to my Python 3.4 installation `C:\Python34`. My `.jam` file now looked like as seen in **Project-Config.jam**.
5. Used `.\b2` in cmd to start the build process. While I had a lot of warnings during the built (`forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)`, etc.), it didn't seem to be any error messages after the built was finished.

**Including**

This is how I created my project in Visual Studio.

1. Created a new project.
2. Added code as seen in **Test Code**.
3. Under VC++ Directories in Project Properties:

   1. Added `C:\boost_1_55_0` to `Include Directories`.
   2. Added `C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib` (the folder where I could find `.lib` files) to `Library Directories`.

---

**Project-Config.jam**

```
import option ; 

using msvc ; 

option.set keep-going : false ; 

using python : 3.4 : C:\\Python34\\python ;
```

**Test Code**

From: `boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\getting_started1.cpp`

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace 
{ 
    // A couple of simple C++ functions that we want to expose to Python.
    std::string greet() { return "hello, world"; }
    int square(int number) { return number * number; }
}

namespace python = boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(getting_started1)
{
    // Add regular functions to the module.
    python::def("greet", greet);
    python::def("square", square);
}
```

Comment: I had this for python, note the multiple include directories: `using python
     : 3.5
     : D:\\temp\\python\\PCbuild\\python.exe # cmd-or-prefix
     : D:\\temp\\python\\include D:\\temp\\cpythonorig\\PC
     : D:\\temp\\python\\PCbuild ;`

Comment: `using python : 3.4 : C:\\Python34\\python ;` -- isn't the tailing `\\python` superfluous?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You think so? I wouldn't know. I just copied it from [KTC's post in this tread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010/2655683#2655683). But I would be happy for anything that helps me catch an error. My project appears to be working as of know, but I have one warning I can't get rid of, `1>c:\python\python34\include\pymath.h(22): warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage` so perhaps I still did something wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems I just needed to add a path to `Python34/include/` and `Python34/libs/` in my Include and Library dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for that, it helped a lot! A note for future visitors, the best way to do this is with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/3524982), rather than adding each directory individually.