# How to get boost.python tutorial to work with Visual Studio 2010 and python 3.4?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I would like to use Boost.python on a Win7 machine for a python 3.4 project
that will connect to our C++ DLL. I'm working my way through the boost.python
tutorial and cannot get it to work (see step 14 below). I don't think this
issue is related to python 3.4 but something easier (missing path settings in
the Visual Studio Command Prompt). I can't figure out how to fix it! Help!

Here are the details of what I'm doing:

As I said it's a Win7 (virtual) Machine and I'm trying to run with 32 bit
python/Visual studio. I do have python 3.4 installed and in the path...

Starting from this discussion:
[How to use Boost in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010)

I do the following:

1. Start Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt:
   `Menu->Programs->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010->Visual Studio Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt`
2. `cd C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0`
3. `bootstrap`
4. `b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete --with-python --libdir=C:\Boost\lib\i386 install`
   Initial warning `link.jam: No such file or directory`

   ```
   C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0>dir C:\Boost\lib\i386
    Volume in drive C has no label.
    Volume Serial Number is BCA0-48C6

    Directory of C:\Boost\lib\i386

   06/19/2014  11:45 AM    <DIR>          .
   06/19/2014  11:45 AM    <DIR>          ..
   06/19/2014  11:45 AM           217,088 boost_python-vc100-1_55.dll
   06/19/2014  11:45 AM           188,908 boost_python-vc100-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:43 AM           496,640 boost_python-vc100-gd-1_55.dll
   06/19/2014  11:43 AM           190,156 boost_python-vc100-gd-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:42 AM           217,088 boost_python-vc100-mt-1_55.dll
   06/19/2014  11:42 AM           190,156 boost_python-vc100-mt-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:25 AM           496,640 boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.dll
   06/19/2014  11:25 AM           191,452 boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:30 AM         5,757,576 libboost_python-vc100-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:29 AM        22,050,448 libboost_python-vc100-gd-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:24 AM         5,758,472 libboost_python-vc100-mt-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:23 AM        22,051,792 libboost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:32 AM         6,247,162 libboost_python-vc100-mt-s-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:31 AM        21,969,684 libboost_python-vc100-mt-sgd-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:35 AM         6,246,266 libboost_python-vc100-s-1_55.lib
   06/19/2014  11:33 AM        21,968,340 libboost_python-vc100-sgd-1_55.lib
                 16 File(s)    114,237,868 bytes
                  2 Dir(s)  14,676,119,552 bytes free
   ```
5. Open Visual Studio 2010 and create New "Empty project" called `Python.Boost`
6. Right Click on `Property Manager->Release|Win32->Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` and select `Properties`
7. Select 'VC++ Directories'
8. Edit the 'Include Directories' to add `C:\Boost\include\boost_1_55_0\boost;C:\Python34\include`
9. Edit the 'Library Directories' to add `C:\Boost\lib\i386;C:\Python34\libs`
10. Following instructions from here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/hello.html
11. Create `user-config.jam` in home directory with following content:

    ```
    #  MSVC configuration
    using msvc : 10.0 ;
    # Python configuration:
    using python : 3.4 : C:\\Python34 : C:\\Python34\\include : C:\\Python34\\libs ;
    ```
12. Open a Windows Command Prompt (started from Python.Boost project through Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt
13. `cd C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial`
14. `bjam`

    ```
    C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial> bjam
    link.jam: No such file or directory
    ...patience... 
    ...patience... 
    ...found 1685 targets... 
    ...updating 6 targets...
    msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd LINK : fatal error LNK1104:
    cannot open file 'boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib'

            call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
            10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >nul link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL
            /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console
            /out:"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd"
            /IMPLIB:"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python34\libs"
            @"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd.rsp" if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT
            %ERRORLEVEL%

    ...failed msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd
    bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pdb
    bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pdb... ...removing
    bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pdb ...skipped <p.>hello_ext.pyd for lack of
    <pbin\msvc-10.0\debug>hello_ext.pyd... ...failed updating 2 targets...
    ...skipped 1 target...
    ```

What am I missing? Seems like the paths are not set as expected? Help appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get boost.python tutorial example to link with Python3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314644/how-to-get-boost-python-tutorial-example-to-link-with-python3)

Comment: Please don't do this twice!! Delete this Q/A in favor of the newer one, or edit to improve!

Comment: What about combining in a single one, they're very similar. Complain at the `boost::python` forums that the docs are poor.

Comment: Ok. I can combine them tomorrow. To late here EST time.

Comment: No problem, I'm friendly! Good night!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this the failure above but I'm running into a new issue (Using Python 3.4 makes the linker fail).

To get around this issue I did the following from the command line:

```
set lib=c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib;C:\Boost\lib\i386;C:\Python34\libs
```

Followed by another `bjam` run. With the modified lib setting the linker finds the correct file. This causes another linking issue when using Python3.4 (I will open a separate request for help with that).

As an experiment I moved back to Python2.7 by modifying my 'config-user.jam' to be this:

```
using python : 2.7 : C:\\Python27 : C:\\Python27\\include : C:\\Python27\\libs ;
```

Then the program successfully linked and I could then run the hello.py program (using python2.7)

The linker issue with 3.4 looks nastier and I've seen comments around it's issue in other places. I will try to use Python 3.2 as well (or any "3" release) to see if that works. I don't need to use 3.4 but I do need at least Python3.