# How to get boost.python tutorial example to link with Python3?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, python-3.x, boost-python

I want to use `boost.python` with `python 3.2+` (preferably 3.4) and Visual Studio 2010.

When I try to make the `libs\python\example\tutorial` example against any Python3 (I have tested 3.0, 3.2 and 3.4) it doesn't link (see below). When I link it against 2.7 it works.

The only change I make between attempts is updating `user-config.jam` in my home directory.

So it **works** when `user-config.jam` is:

```
#  MSVC configuration
using msvc : 10.0 ;
# Python configuration:
using python : 2.7 : C:\\Python27 : C:\\Python27\\include : C:\\Python27\\libs ;
```

When I run `bjam` I get:

```
C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial>bjam
link.jam: No such file or directory
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1678 targets...
...updating 8 targets...
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello.obj
hello.cpp
msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd
   Creating library bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib and object bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.exp
   msvc.manifest.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd
   common.copy boost_python-vc100-gd-1_55.dll
   ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug\boost_python-vc100-gd-1_55.dll
           1 file(s) copied.
common.copy hello_ext.pyd
bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd
           1 file(s) copied.
capture-output bin\hello.test\msvc-10.0\debug\hello
           1 file(s) copied.
**passed** bin\hello.test\msvc-10.0\debug\hello.test
...updated 8 targets...
```

If I change `user-config.jam` to:

```
#  MSVC configuration
using msvc : 10.0 ;
# Python configuration:
using python : 3.4 : C:\\Python34 : C:\\Python34\\include : C:\\Python34\\libs ;
```

and to `bjam clean` and then `bjam` I get:

```
C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial>bjam
link.jam: No such file or directory
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1685 targets...
...updating 9 targets...
compile-c-c++ bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello.obj
hello.cpp
msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd
   Creating library bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib and object bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.exp
   hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct _object * __cdecl boost::python::detail::init_module(struct PyModuleDef &,void (__cdecl*)(void))" (__imp_?init_module@detail@python@boost@@YAPAU_object@@AAUPyModuleDef@@P6AXXZ@Z) referenced in function _PyInit_hello_ext
   bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

           call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console /out:"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd" /IMPLIB:"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python34\libs"   @"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd.rsp"
           if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

...failed msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pdb bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pdb...
...removing bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib
...removing bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pdb
common.copy boost_python-vc100-gd-1_55.dll
..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug\boost_python-vc100-gd-1_55.dll
           1 file(s) copied.
...skipped <p.>hello_ext.pyd for lack of <pbin\msvc-10.0\debug>hello_ext.pyd...
...failed updating 3 targets...
...skipped 1 target...
...updated 2 targets...
```

Looking online I find a couple of references to this error but no solutions...
Here is the best link:

http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2011/06/25147.php

I have seen many people talking about using Python3 and boost.python so I must be missing something... *Do I need to compile boost specifically for Python 3 somehow?*

Help?

/Robert

Comment: OK, I've upvoted some of your Q&A here. Hopefully gave you some pointers, at least we're peering on commenting abilities now! You're welcome! I'm interested to read more helpful questions or answers written on SO by you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So through trial and error I found a way that works.

I am not able to recompile a boost library from Python27 to Python34 **but** if I start from a clean area (i.e freshly 7zipped) and do the following it works (all in a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt):

1. Make sure you have a `user-config.jam` file in your home directory with the following content:

   ```
   #  MSVC configuration
   using msvc : 10.0 ;
   # Python configuration:
   using python : 3.4 : C:\\Python34 : C:\\Python34\\include : C:\\Python34\\libs ;
   ```
2. `cd C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0`
3. `bootstrap`
4. `b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete --with-python --libdir=C:\Boost\lib\i386 install`
5. `cd C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial`
6. `set lib=c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib;C:\Boost\lib\i386;C:\Python34\libs` (i.e add Boost Lib to path)
7. `bjam`
8. Modify hello.py to att `()` around print:

   ```
   import hello_ext
   print(hello_ext.greet())
   ```
9. `python hello.py` prints `hello, world` (Note that python here is python 3.4.1 my default install)

So what I still don't know how to solve is how to recompile boost and/or how to support two python version at the same time. Ideas and suggestions are welcomed but at the moment I only need Python3 so I will not investigate that.

Another thing to note is that the pre-compiled headers found online all seem to be 2.7 only. I hope these steps helps someone else!