# Cant get boost::thread to work with MSVS2013

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, boost, boost-thread

i am trying to use Boost:thread for a simple http client i am working on.

I cannot get it to work, every other boost lib i am using is working fine.

this is the error i am geting:

```
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Client::add_user(void)" (?add_user@Client@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Client::commandBuilder(void)" (?commandBuilder@Client@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)    C:\Users\Or\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\client\client\Client.obj  client
```

note that i am geting 8 very similiar errors.

this is my include code:

```
#include <boost\thread.hpp>
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
```

I have built the libs using this command in the VS developer cmd:

```
bjam toolset=msvc-12.0 --build-type=complete --with-thread --with-chrono --with-date_time
```

also both my include paths for VC++ and the Linker are set to the right paths.

I am a bit lost here, i have tried building the whole boost again from scratch using this guide:

[How to use Boost in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010)

and still did not help.

any help would be appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, apparntly all the building and building damaged my boost install.

Removed every trace of boost from my computer.

Reinstalled it by doing the following steps:

1. going to the boost dir using vs developer command line tools shortcut
2. `bootstrap`
3. `b2`
4. ```
   bjam toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete --with-thread --with-chrono --     with-date_time
   ```
5. reconfiguring all the libs to the right ones.
6. using `#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`