# Boost library installation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

I downloaded boost 1.57. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

I added `mypath\boost_1_57_0` to additional include directories.

I also added `mypath\boost_1_57_0\libs` into additional library directories.

In my code I just want to add a library `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` , but I get this error.

```
Error   5   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-sgd-1_57.lib'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is a bad question because a cursory google search will show you how to link against boost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Boost in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Did you solve your problem based on the link provided by Mikhail, or do you still need help?

Comment: I did how it has been said there and it worked. But it took an hour and 30 min to bootstrap those files and the final folder has over 2GB

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc You can delete the intermediate build files, which will shave quite a bit off that figure. They're usually in `bin.v2`, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I have no such files there. Only libs and dlls.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc There should be a `bin.v2` directory under the `boost` root directory (which was the current directory when you ran `b2`).

Comment: You are right. Deleted that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open you property page,in "Configuration Properties"->"Linker"->"Input"->"Additional Dependcies"，add the "libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-sgd-1_57.lib";