# Can't compile boost.python 1.65.1 with MSVC2015

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to generate Boost.Python 1.65.1 libraries with MSVC2015 and Python 3.7.

I'm having this compilation error:

```
libs\python\src\converter\builtin_converters.cpp(51): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'void *'
libs\python\src\converter\builtin_converters.cpp(51): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
```

The associated code (error is on the return) :

```
void* convert_to_cstring(PyObject* obj)
{
  return PyUnicode_Check(obj) ? _PyUnicode_AsString(obj) : 0;
}
```

It looks like a real error to me. Is there an option in the b2 configuration to make the compiler more flexible on this ?

I used this as information:

https://codeyarns.com/2014/06/06/how-to-build-boost-using-visual-studio/

[How to use Boost in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010)

Edit: I don't have this error with boost 1.69.0, but I have to use the 1.65.1

Edit2: They changed this code in 1.69.0:

```
PyUnicode_Check(obj) ? const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(_PyUnicode_AsString(obj))) : 0;
```

Comment: It could be that 1.65.1 is known to have this bug with your compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a known issue, Boost.python didn't compile with Python 3.7. It's been fixed in Boost.python 1.67.

The fix is very simple and you can backport [the patch](https://github.com/boostorg/python/commit/660487c43fde76f3e64f1cb2e644500da92fe582#diff-467cabb22a6c637452d730accca26d2e) to your local copy manually or just cast the result of `_PyUnicode_AsString()` to `(void*)` in `libs/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp(51)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Btw, where do you find this kind of information please ? I always have trouble when googling this kind of stuff about boost

Comment: Just the [commit history](https://github.com/boostorg/python/commits/develop/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp) and/or git [blame](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blame/develop/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp) of the relevant file..