# Building Boost for Ogre 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, cmake, bjam, ogre

Needing to add the 64 bit version of the Ogre graphics engine (latest at the time of writing this post, i.e. 1.8.0), I've followed [their hints](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Prerequisites) and opened a visual c++ x64 command prompt and typed this:

```
  bjam --build-dir=vc10 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --address_model=64 --with-thread --with-date_time --build-type=complete stage
```

This is as far as I got with convincing boost to build lib objects for a 64 bit windows compiler. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Premium and the CMake tools to compile Ogre from sources. This is where things get nasty:

```
 Error  276 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\OgreMain_d.lib'    
 Error  119 error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

I fear I won't make it pass this issue any time soon as I'm totally unaccustomed to working with big code bases that rely heavily on dependencies that I have to, also, build from scratch. Could you please provide a hint or a link to something I might have missed? Thanks..

**UPDATE**
There is a website containing the already built libraries, but it would be nice to learn why the *--address-model* and *--address-space* flags don't work. How else should one use *bjam* to build the libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in the bjam command.  You don't want a `--` in front of `toolset` or `address-model`, and `address-model` has a hyphen, not an underscore.

So the command you probably were aiming for is:

```
bjam --build-dir=vc10 toolset=msvc-10.0 address-model=64 --with-thread --with-date_time --build-type=complete stage
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to do two things: get my eyes checked and correct the Ogre official tutorials (as they use --toolset). No wonder address_model was not recognized as a valid flag by _bjam_

Answer (score 1):

The first error is self explanatory - The lib file does not exist in the path specified.
The second error indicates that you're building for 64-bit but one of the dependency libraries being used is compiled for 32-bit.

Comment: Quite clear about that, the first error might be a problem cause by the exact issue in my question: how to build those boost libraries for 64 bit compilers? although I've used the boost 'bjam' with the '--address_model=64' flag from within the MS VC prompt, it didn't produce '.libs' for a 64 bit target (I checked this with the 'dumpbin' utility). I think that if I get rid of the 64 vs 32 problem, I will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download precompiled Boost binaries from [there](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) and install it into default location. This will make CMake to properly locate library and include dirs.

Comment: I already did that, all of them are 32 bit. For the 64 bit I have found a version listed in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322255/64-bit-version-of-boost-for-64-bit-windows) SO thread as an answer (the second I believe)