# Easier way to specify Additional Library locations in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

When i build the boost library, with the vs 2013 developer prompt,

```
>bootstrap
>b2
```

it will generate the lib files in an subdirectory:

```
bin.v2
```

every library is now saved as follows(example):

```
 <path>\boost_1_55_0\bin.v2_x64\libs\log\build\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\link-static\log-api-winnt\threading-multi\libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib
```

Now when i try to build an app which uses logging, i will get an linker error because the

file 'libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'
could not be opened. Now, when i specify the location of this file in the linker properties of my project and rebuild it another file is missing:

libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib

rinse and repeat and yet another dependency will pop up, libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib  and so on, is there a smart way to solve this problem? like building the boost libraries in a way that the boost build programm will put them in one single folder or can i configure visual studio to search recursively for the libs?

Comment: Isn't it enough to put the library path `\boost_1_55_0\bin.v2_x64\libs\log\build\msvc-12.0\debug\address-model-64\architecture-x86\link-static\log-api-winnt\threading-multi` just once and specify the several `.lib` files? I don't exactly get what you're asking for (but I'm also not that frequently using VS)

Comment: no because they are in different directories that's the problem thererfore vs does not find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else asked a question on how to build x64 libs with bjam: [64-bit version of Boost for 64-bit windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322255/64-bit-version-of-boost-for-64-bit-windows)

the answer also contained the answer to this concrete question:
after the bootstrap command, the bjam command goes as follows:

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-12.0 --build-type=complete allthelibs
```

where --toolset=msvc-12.0 corresponds to visual studio 2013

and allthelibs will be the subfolder containing all the boostlibs